# Fluent BQL producing unexpected SQL for join

Tags: acumatica, fluent

I'm using Fluent BQL to join a CreatedByID column to Users, to get the user name (simple example below).

```
public SelectFrom<GIDesign>
    .InnerJoin<CreatedUsers>.On<CreatedUsers.pKID.IsEqual<GIDesign.createdByID>>
    .OrderBy<GIDesign.name.Asc>.View GIs;
```

However, the SQL join condition ends up like this...

```
INNER JOIN [Users] [CreatedUsers_Users] ON NULL = [GIDesign].[CreatedByID] 
AND ( [CreatedUsers_Users].[CompanyID] IN ( 1, 2) 
AND 8 = SUBSTRING( [CreatedUsers_Users].[CompanyMask], 1, 1) & 8) 
AND [CreatedUsers_Users].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0
```

The join condition NULL = CreatedByID is of course returning no records. I tried swapping the left and right side of the join and then get this as the first join condition:

```
INNER JOIN [Users] [CreatedUsers_Users] ON [GIDesign].[CreatedByID] = 
AND ...
```

Notice the missing right side of the equation? What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Tony, what tool do you use to see the SQL that is sent?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself shortly after I posted this.  I removed the PXProjection attributes, added a Serializable attribute, plus removed PK member classes I had added to try to resolve the issue. So one of these changes must have been the key.